# Conditionally Add a Class to an Element with Om

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, om

In Om, is there a way to add a class to an element based on some value in the main app atom?

Take the following element, for example:

```
(defn some-component [app owner]
  (reify
    om/IRender
    (render
      [_]
      (html
        [:div {:class (when (:some-key app) "awesomeclass")} "Some text!"]))))
```

If I somehow toggle the value of `:some-key` between true and false, the class doesn't get added or removed. The value of `:some-key` on page load determines whether or not the class gets added.

I am using this idea to conditionally show/hide (using Twitter Bootstrap's `hide` class) menu options based on the value of the `:access` key in my app state:

```
[:ul.dropdown-menu {:role "menu"}
  [:li {:class (when (:access app) "hide")} [:a.pointer {:on-click #(om/update! app :view :login)} "Login"]]
  [:li {:class (when (:access app) "hide")} [:a.pointer {:on-click #(om/update! app :view :register)} "Register"]]
  [:li {:class (when-not (:access app) "hide")} [:a.pointer {:on-click #(om/update! app :view :dashboard)} "Dashboard"]]
  [:li {:class (when-not (:access app) "hide")} [:a.pointer {:on-click #(om/update! app :view :settings)} "Settings"]]
  [:li [:a.pointer {:on-click #(om/update! app :view :about)} "About"]]]
```

Comment: How do you toggle `:some-key`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works as expected. When I click on "Click Me!", while looking at the Elements in Developer Tools (Chrome), I see the class toggling between "awesomeclass" and disappearing:

```clj
 (defonce app-state (atom {:some-key true}))

 (defn main []
   (om/root
     (fn [app owner]
       (reify
         om/IRender
         (render [_]
           (html
            [:div {:class (when (:some-key app) "awesomeclass")}
             "Some text!"
             [:a {:on-click #(om/transact! app :some-key not)}
              "Click Me!"]]))))
     app-state
     {:target (. js/document (getElementById "app"))}))
```

As [rojoca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41967/rojoca) pointed out, the problem might be in the way you update `app-state`, consider using `om/transact!` and `om/update!`. If you keep having problems, post the code that updates the state.

Note: I'm running this in [Chestnut](https://github.com/plexus/chestnut).

Comment: This was the issue.. I was using `swap!` instead of `om/transact!` and the like. This is why we RTFM

Answer (score 0):

You should use the keyword `:className` instead of `:class`.

Comment: This would be true if I was using `om.dom`. I am using `sablono` which normalizes many of the attributes. See [here](https://github.com/r0man/sablono#html-attributes)